# Can mocked methods be removed from a FlexMock object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mocking

Given a mock object, I want to re-mock a method several times during the life of the object, like so:

```
mock = flexmock
[ :foo, :bar ].each do |val|
  mock.should_receive(:my_method).and_return val
  assert_equal val, mock.my_method, "my_method"
end
```

However, running this test fails for :bar

```
my_method.
<:bar> expected but was
<:foo>.
```

Basically, FlexMock will not update an existing expectation. Any ideas (other than "use Mocha / another mocking framework)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It involves hacking on the FlexMock object directly, but that is The Ruby Way, after all! ;)

```
  def clear_mocked_method(mock, method)
    mock.instance_eval { @expectations.delete method.to_sym }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

in Rspec I would use contexts to do this and mock it How I expected it to be in a series of tests. ( Then it would be different in the next context for the next series)

You might have to give up some compactness for some correctness.

Comment: Will you please provide an example? I can't quite follow your suggestion. Thanks!